# Deploy from expired Project to new devloper org using eclipse

Tags: apex, api

I went on the Dev 501 apex training course a while back, but at the time i forgot to transfer the org we used on the course to a new development environment. As a result my training org has now expired.

I still have the files locally in eclipse, so my question is: is there a way to deploy the expired org from eclipse to a new developer org in one hit?

Comment: Are you just trying to deploy the Apex you created or all the instance settings? If the first then you can just select all the classes you want to deploy in eclipse then right click and select Deploy to Server. Then enter the new server details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have the code and the meta files locally on your machine.

1. back up those local files
2. right click on the project folder and click properties
3. change the credentials to point at the new environment.
4. if your local files get overwritten, copy your code back into the src/classes folder
5. refresh the eclipse src folder (locally, not from salesforce)
6. highlight the files and right-click force.com->save to server.

The files will be posted to the new dev org as long as your dependencies are met (objects, ect).

Answer (score 0):

I usually just zip up the arc directory from the locked out project and unzip into a new project outside of eclipse. Then when I start eclipse it deploys the new elements to the server. It's basically the way that the code shares work.